# Ensure successful execution of script on remote server

Tags: shell

I have a script on a local system which invokes a script on the remote server (server A) to execute. The command in script which triggers remote server script looks like

```
ssh <user>@<server ip> "bash -s < ./shell_backup_trx_db.sh"
```

Script `shell_backup_trx_db.sh` on remote server takes database backup and puts it on server A file system. How can I ensure inside the script on local which uses the above command that the ssh command executed successfully and continue script execution ahead or else abort it?

Comment: Why are you using `bash -s < ./shell_backup_trx_db.sh` instead of just `bash shell_backup_trx_db.sh`? And if your script exist with a failure return code then I believe ssh will as well and you can test for that locally.

Comment: thanks @EtanReisner for your response not sure about -s parameter, I just found it while googling for executing script via ssh. Also what if due to any reason ssh command could not connect to remote server, does ssh in that case will return somthing?

Comment: If it is unable to connect, it will return an error, which means that your next script won't run if you use `&&`

Comment: thanks @Chirag64 the script has much more to execute. So I am thinking to do something like if [ssh ...] and in else part I aborting the script execution by exit, do you think it will be good approach. Thanks again for your answer, I really appreciate.

Comment: `if ! ssh ...; then echo ssh failed; exit; done`

Comment: @EtanReisner something similar
if [ ssh <user>@<server ip> " -f shell_backup_trx_db.sh"] then continue ... else echo "failed,aborting" exit fi, looks good to you?

Comment: No, `[` is a command not part of the `if` syntax. Using your command you would get an error from `[` as it cannot understand its arguments. To test the return code of a command you don't need `[`. `if ! ssh <user>@<server ip> -f shell_backup_trx_db.sh; then echo ...; exit; fi` You could avoid using `!` to negate the test but I don't see why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the remote script returns an appropriate exit code, you shouldn't have a problem to do this.

Just use the conditional control operator `&&` which continues with the next command only if the previous command exited without an error:

`ssh <user>@<server ip> "/path/to/shell_backup_trx_db.sh" && echo "Done with backup"`

Edit: If you want to execute multiple commands based on whether the ssh command passes or fails, you can use an `if..else..fi` statement.

Example:

```
if ssh <user>@<server ip> "/path/to/shell_backup_trx_db.sh";
then
  echo "Backup completed successfully";
  ./next_script.sh;
else
  echo "Backup failed";
  exit;
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

To exit your script when ssh fails (for whatever reason) you can use something like this.

```
if ! ssh ...; then
    echo ssh failed
    exit
fi
```

Comment: @Chirag64 Absolutely correct. Context switching problem there. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Chirag and @Etan for their valuable answers, with their help ended up with.

```
  if ssh <user>@<server-ip> stat shell_backup_trx_db.sh \> /dev/null 2\>\&1
  then
    # Trigger Production Database back for both mysql and mongo.
   ssh <user>@<server-ip> "bash -s < ./shell_backup_trx_db.sh"

   echo "Database backup successfully completed."

   # Prompt user to check manually that database backup is completed successfully.
   read -p "Ensure database backup process is successfully completed. Login to dev/stg server and run 'ls command'. Press [Enter] key to continue execution."
  else 
    # Backup script could not be accessed, abort script execution any further. 
    echo "Back up script not found, aborting script execution, Please take backup before." 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
```